# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined js

Tags: discord.js

this is the code -

module.exports = {
name: 'clear',
description: "Clear messages!",
async execute(message, args) {
if (!args[0]) return message.reply("Please enter the amount of messages to clear!");

```
    if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Please type a real number!");

    if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply("You can't remove more than 100 messages!");
    
    if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply("You have to delete at least one message!");

    await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: args[0]}).then(messages =>{
        message.channel.bulkDelete(messages)
});
```

}
}
the error -

```
    if(command === 'clear'){
    client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
}
```

Comment: You need to show more of the file, such as how you set `client.commands` etc.

Answer (score 0):

sorry the command execute is -

```
    if(command === 'clear'){
    client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
}
```

and the error -

```
C:\Users\heyno\Desktop\DiscordBot2\main.js:33
    client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = { 
    name: 'clear', 
    description: "Clear messages!", 
    execute: async function(message, args) { // here were your issue
        if (!args[0]) 
            return message.reply("Please enter the amount of messages to clear!");

        if(isNaN(args[0])) 
            return message.reply("Please type a real number!");

        if(args[0] > 100) 
            return message.reply("You can't remove more than 100 messages!");

        if(args[0] < 1) 
            return message.reply("You have to delete at least one message!");

        message.channel.bulkDelete(parseInt(args[0]));
    } 
}
```